# How to get status value string from razorpay array

Tags: php

```
Razorpay\Api\Payment Object ( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => pay_IOx1H64JMSEFAv [entity] => payment [amount] => 100 [currency] => INR [status] => captured [order_id] => order_IOx0xic60K6TZi [invoice_id] => [international] => [method] => wallet [amount_refunded] => 0 [refund_status] => [captured] => 1 [description] => [card_id] => [bank] => [wallet] => payzapp [vpa] => [email] => sudiptobain8@gmail.com [contact] => +919134322935 [notes] => Razorpay\Api\Payment Object ( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [shopping_order_id] => 3456 ) ) [fee] => 2 [tax] => 0 [error_code] => [error_description] => [error_source] => [error_step] => [error_reason] => [acquirer_data] => Razorpay\Api\Payment Object ( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [transaction_id] => ) ) [created_at] => 1637649968 ) )
```

help to get `[status] => captured` From This in php

Comment: I hope you are not using real data to ask your question. I see phone number and email.

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture objects using object (arrow) notation

```
<?php
echo $result->status;
?>
```